# Entity Framework - Fluent API - Erro

Tags: entity-framework

Estou seguindo [este tutorial](http://netcoders.com.br/mapeamento-com-entity-framework-code-first-fluent-api-parte-2/). Ao criar a classe abaixo deu um erro:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Domain.entities;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;

namespace DataAccess.Map
{
    public class CursoMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Curso>
    {
        public CursoMap()
        {
            /*O método ToTable define qual o nome que será
            dado a tabela no banco de dados*/
            ToTable("Curso");

            //Definimos a propriedade CursoId como chave primária
            HasKey(x => x.CursoId);

            //Descricao terá no máximo 150 caracteres e será um campo "NOT NULL"
            Property(x => x.Descricao).HasMaxLength(150).IsRequired();

            HasMany(x => x.ProfessorLista)
                      .WithMany(x => x.CursoLista)
                      .Map(m =>
                      {
                          m.MapLeftKey("CursoId");
                          m.MapRightKey("ProfessorId");
                          m.ToTable("CursoProfessor");
                      });
        }
    }
}
```

O erro aconteceu nas seguintes partes: `HasKey(x => x.CursoId);` `Property(x => x.Descricao)` `HasMany(x => x.ProfessorLista)`

Mensagem do erro:

> Error 1   The type arguments for method
>
> 'System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.EntityTypeConfiguration.HasK
>
> ey(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>)'
>
> cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments
>
> explicitly.

Classe Curso:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Domain.entities
{
    class Curso
    {
        public Curso()
        {
            ProfessorLista = new List<Professor>();
            Ativo = true;
        }
        public int CursoId { get; set; }

        public string Numero { get; set; }

        public string Descricao { get; set; }

        public bool Ativo { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Professor> ProfessorLista { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Descricao;
        }
    }
}
```

O que preciso fazer?

Comment: Coloque a classe curso

Comment: Coloquei a classe curso.

Comment: Em qual momento da o erro? Outro ponto o mapeamento falta alguns campos o porque?

Comment: Olha, eu só estou seguindo o tutorial, não entendo dessa sintaxe. O erro apareceu quando eu criei essa classe. O que falta exatamente? Deve ser por isso que está dando erro.

Comment: Bom, vou seguir com o tutorial e ver no que dá.

Comment: Bom a classe Curso deveria ser `public class Curso` faltou colocar `public`, outro ponto essas classes todas possui relacionamento, se tiver alguma classe faltando ou algo pode ocasionar erros, antes de mais nada siga todo o tutorial ...

Comment: Era isso mesmo, faltou o public em class Curso. Como ficaria a resposta para este post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema foi resolvido. Faltou o `public` na classe `Curso`.